# Why is the fundamental group of the plane with two holes non-abelian?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I know $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{x,y\}) = \mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z} = \langle a,b\rangle$, but its non-abelian-ness isn't obvious to me.

Specifically, I draw a box and two points to represent $x$ and $y$. I call the clockwise loop around $x$ $a$, and the clockwise loop around $y$, $b$.

If I draw the loops $ab$ and $ba$ they look `obviously homotopic' to me (they are both a single clockwise loop containing both $x$ and $y$), so should be the same element in $\pi_1$, which is clearly not the case if we take the *free* product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself.

It seems that I must be making a big mistake somewhere. What is the obstruction to $ab \simeq ba$? I would prefer something concrete, I know this fundamental group follows from standard theorems (van Kampen's theorem), but I want to see the homotopy fail, because I think they are pretty clearly homotopic - so there is something wrong with my intuition which I'd like to fix.

Comment: Do you believe that $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are not homotopic? There's a question of order here. It's not just the image of the map that counts.

Comment: @Hoot I do believe $a \not\simeq a^{-1}$ because they traverse around $x$ in different directions, and there's no homotopy between them because any such map would have to pass through $x$.

Comment: use [universal covering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Universal_covers)

Comment: The information contained in the notion "clockwise" is purely homological and on the homology level you cannot tell $ab$ from $ba$.

Comment: The fact that homotopies have to fix the basepoint is important here.

Answer (score 36):

An important detail is that the fundamental group is built from loops that all start and end at a common *base point*.  We know that some loops can be continuously deformed into other loops; these loops are called homotopically equivalent. As a special case, some loops can be continuously deformed into other loops *while keeping the base point fixed in place*.

The fundamental group consists of loops which are considered equivalent when they are **homotopic in this special base-point-preserving sense**. The fundamental group fails to be commutative when there are loops that are homotopically equivalent in the generic sense, and yet not homotopically equivalent in the base-preserving sense.

In pictures, below you can see the plane with two holes along with three loops *a, b, c* with a common base point.

[image]

Note that you can't continuously deform b into c unless you're allowed to move the base point. (This is our signal that the fundamental group doesn't commute, which we'll show in more detail.)

> Loops b and c aren't homotopic in a way that preserves the base point. Therefore, b ≢ c in the fundamental group.

Even so, b and c are homotopic in the general sense. For example, one (non-base-point-preserving) homotopy from b to c involves sliding the base point around the lower hole:

[image]

A neat observation is that during this homotopy, the trajectory of the base point is recognizable as loop a!

> Loops b and c are homotopic in the general sense. The trajectory of the base point under that homotopy is loop a.

From this, it follows that there's a base-preserving homotopy between loop c•a ("go around the hole, then perform c") and loop a•b ("perform b, then go around the hole"):

[image]

> Loops c•a and a•b are equivalent in the fundamental group. In other words, loops b and c are *conjugates*:
>   $$ca \equiv ab$$ $$c \equiv a\cdot b \cdot a^{-1}$$

If the fundamental group were abelian, then this conjugacy would imply that b = c. Because b ≢ c, the fundamental group is nonabelian.

---

In general, when there's a homotopy between two loops *b* and *c*, let *a* be the trajectory of the base point under that homotopy. Then a is itself a loop with the same base point as b and c, and c= aba⁻¹ (b and c are conjugates). If there isn't a base-preserving homotopy, then a is nontrivial and b ≢ c, so the fundamental group isn't abelian.

---

Final comment: Note that from the beginning, the source of the problem (noncommutativity) is the presence of holes. We saw intuitively that we could deform b into c, but only by moving the base point— there's a hole in the way.  Now we can see that property emerge algebraically:

Loops b and c are deformable into one another when they're conjugate c= aba⁻¹.  The element *a* describes the trajectory of the base point during that deformation. So if they're deformable without moving the base point, this is equivalent to saying that conjugacy holds when *a* is trivial  (topologically, *a* is the constant loop at the base point; algebraically, it's the multiplicative unit) in which case we have b = c. Otherwise, if we *must* move the base point in order to deform one loop into the other, this is equivalent to saying that conjugacy c= aba⁻¹ only holds for a nontrivial choice of loop *a*. A loop is nontrivial just when it encircles a hole (!), hence this is an algebraic way of saying that a hole (call it hole A) stands in the way of deforming b into c.

Comment: Nice answer, more than expected!! Are these images have been taken from a book? if so, book name pls.

Comment: @C.F.G Thanks! No, I drew them myself --- I used Inkscape to do it.

Comment: Great. Sorry I have used [your image in my post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3834706/272127). I think you can answer to that post that has not received any answer yet.

Comment: @C.F.G Sure, I'm glad you found the image useful.

Comment: Could I use your pictures in my bachelor thesis?

Comment: @FrancescoScavella Yeah! Glad they're helpful. I'd be curious to see the figures in your thesis when it's finished, if you want to share.

Comment: @user326210 Thank you so much! No problem (Just wanna let you know that the thesis will be written in Italian).

Comment: @FrancescoScavella Sounds good!

Answer (score 3):

If they are "clearly homotopic," then you should be able to present a homotopy.  If you cannot see the homotopy, then what a strange meaning you have for it being "clear"! :-)

Your winding number argument doesn't imply a homotopy, but it does end up having to do with the *homology* of the space, where indeed $ab$ and $ba$ are homologous paths.

I think the best way of seeing that $ab$ and $ba$ are not homotopic is through universal covering spaces or by thinking carefully about how proof of the van Kampen theorem works in this case, but instead of explaining these, I will describe an object that should exist if $ab$ and $ba$ were homotopic but whose existence seems intuitively implausible.

A homotopy $ab\simeq ba$ is equivalent to a map $f:S^1\times S^1\to \mathbb{R}^2-\{x,y\}$ where $f(t,s_0)=a(t)$ and $f(t_0,s)=b(s)$. (Take the $I\times I$ square, with $ab$ on the bottom, $ba$ on the top, and $x_0$ on the left- and right-sides.  Quotient the left- and right-sides each to a point to get a function with $a$ on the bottom and top and $b$ on the sides.)  That is, if you imagine a torus with $\alpha$ the major circumference and $\beta$ the minor circumference, then the map is from a torus into the twice-punctured plane mapping $\alpha$ to $a$ and $\beta$ to $b$.  How exactly is the rest of this torus going to avoid $x$ and $y$? (I'm not aware of an elementary argument that gives an obstruction.)