# Direct proof of non-commuting loops of figure-eight?

Tags: homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

The van Kampen theorem implies that the fundamental group of the figure-eight, being the wedge product of two circles, is not abelian.

How can one prove *directly* that the path-product of the loop $\alpha$ around one of the two circles and the loop $\beta$ around the other (both at the point where the circles are joined) *does* depend on their order, i.e., that $\alpha \beta$ is not path-homotopic to $\beta \alpha$?

Surely there must be a way!

Comment: It’s probably not hard to see that their lifts to the universal cover terminate at different ends, so they can’t have been homotopic.

Comment: @Randall: Still, this seems like something that one ought to be able to do directly, without any such tools as fundamental group, van Kampen theorem, or covering spaces. The space is simple enough, the particular loops are very concrete, the square which wants to show no homotopy between those two particular path-products live at its tops and bottoms is simple enough, too.

Comment: I don’t know, I would call covering spaces a basic tool.   How do you compute the fundamental group of the circle?

Comment: @Randall: for the circle, one can path-lift from interval to line explicitly, prove homotopy-lifting, and prove the circle is not simply connected, hence not a retract of the disk, without mentioning or constructing any group. (See, e.g., Section 5.5 of my "Topology".) I didn't ask to compute fundamental group of the figure-eight; rather, about showing the non-commuting, up to homotopy, of products of two particular loops there. It seems to me desirable to do something simple like that without developing machinery of fundamental group, covering spaces, etc. -- as motivation for that machinery!

Comment: When you say "one can path-lift from interval to line explicitly", that explicit process of path lifting is done..... how? I'd be surprised if you can describe it without invoking explicit processes that are carried out abstractly in the *proof* of the path lifting lemma for covering spaces.

Comment: Having said that, in your most recent comment replace "interval" with "wedge of two circles" and replace "line" by "4-valent tree", and all those things you talk about can be done: path lifting; prove homotopy-lifting; prove the wedge of two circles is not simply connected; etc. *And*, as the first comment of @Randall says, see that the lifts of $\alpha\beta$ and of $\beta\alpha$ to the 4-valent tree terminate at different ends.

Comment: What does *directly* mean to you?

Comment: @Tyrone: "directly" means to me *without* first developing the general theory of covering spaces, fundamental group, van Kampen theorem, etc.; in other words, doing it "from scratch" just for the particular example at hand. (The whole point of my wanting to do so is to serve as *motivation*, via a concrete example, for that general theory &mdash; somethng that many or most treatments of the subject neglect. I always prefer going from the concrete to the general pedagogically.)

Comment: You might like to check out my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834706/visualizing-that-fundamental-group-is-not-abelian-in-general) for a sketch proof which makes no use of covering space theory, van-Kampen or algebraic arguments. I doubt it falls under what you might classify as 'direct'. On the other hand, I can't think of a single example of such a calculation that is done 'directly'. Even to compute $\pi_1S^1$ directly requires a rudimentary and ad-hoc treatment of some covering space theory.

Comment: OP might be interested in what happens with this post:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834706/visualizing-that-fundamental-group-is-not-abelian-in-general

Comment: @Tyrone: Your comment to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3834706/32337 uses "general theory" about mapping cones, homotopy equivalence of spaces, etc. (And how does one prove the non-homeomoprhic relation between the torus and the triple wedge product of the circle with itself?

Comment: @C.F.G: But in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3062396/32337 how does one in fact prove that the loops $b$ and $c$ are not path-homotopic?

Comment: If you fix the base point then you cannot. Do you want an algebraic proof?

Comment: Murray, I suggested it would not fall under what you would describe as 'direct', although I did state what machinery I explicitly avoided. I linked to a post indicating the non-equivalance of the torus and the wedge sum.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Yes, when lifting paths from the circle to the line, I am carrying out, for this particular situation, what I will *eventually* do in the general situation. That's the whole point: to give a specific, particular, concrete example as a pedagogical prelude to the general situation. Yes, this is the reverse of the way mathematicians present their research, but what I am doing is not that kind of research; it's teaching, where I want to motivate the general and abstract by the particular and concrete. This seems to be an approach that some seem hard to get their heads around!

Comment: I don't disagree, and that was the point of my previous comment: you can describe all those objects in my comment explicitly, and prove the individual things you need to prove about them. I would say that most algebraic topology books/courses are content to carry that out for the one example $\mathbb R \to S^1$ given by $t \to (\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$, use that to motivate the definition of covering spaces, and then go straight to the abstract proof for all covering spaces. But, more examples (like the 4-valent tree covering the wedge of two circles) are certainly good.